# How to use/understand lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following method:

```
private byte[] GetEmailAsBytes(string lstrBody)
{
   byte[] lbytBody;
   ASCIIEncoding lASCIIEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
   lbytBody = lASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(lstrBody);
   return lbytBody;
}
```

I was wondering if this could be converted to a lambda expression. Im new to this. I have tried:

```
Func<string> BodyToBytes = x => {
        ASCIIEncoding lASCIIEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        return lASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(x);
}
```

but this does not compile. Simply i wish to convert a string to a series of bytes, and for interest sake would like to do this using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `Func<string>` is equivalent to a function which accepts no arguments and returns a `string`.

Your example clearly returns a `byte[]`, but you *want* it to accept a `string` and return a `byte[]`.

To solve this, change `BodyToBytes` to match the following. Note that the type of the arguments come first, comma delimited, followed by the return type. In this case, `x` will be of type `string`.

```
Func<string, byte[]> BodyToBytes = x => {
        ASCIIEncoding lASCIIEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        return lASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(x);
}
```

For a reference, see [Func Type](http://www.dotnetperls.com/func) or the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have writeen a NUnit Example for my personal understanding.

```
    private class ld
    {
        public Boolean make<T>(T param, Func<T, bool> func) 
        {
            return func(param);
        }
    }

    private class box
    {
        public Boolean GetTrue() { return true; }
        public int Secret = 5;
    }

    [Test]
    public void shouldDemonstrateLambdaExpressions()
    {
        //Normal Boolean Statement with integer
        int a = 5;
        Assert.IsTrue(a == 5);
        Assert.IsFalse(a == 4);

        //Boolean Statement Expressed Via Simple Lambda Expression
        Func<int, bool> myFunc = x => x == 5;
        Assert.IsTrue(myFunc(5));
        Assert.IsFalse(myFunc(4));

        //Encapsuled Lambda Expression Called on Integer By Generic Class with integer
        ld t = new ld();
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make<int>(5,myFunc));
        Assert.IsFalse(t.make<int>(4, myFunc));

        //Encapsuled Lambda Expression Called on Integer By Generic Class with implicit Generics
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(5, myFunc));

        //Simple Lambda Expression Called on Integer By Generic Class with implicit Generic
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(20, (x => x == 20)));
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(20, (x => x > 12)));
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(20, (x => x < 100)));
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(20, (x => true)));

        //Simple Lambda Expression Called on a Class By Generic Class with implicit Generic 
        //FULL LAMBDA POWER REACHED
        box b = new box();
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(b, (x => x.GetTrue())));
        Assert.IsTrue(t.make(b, (x => x.Secret == 5)));
        Assert.IsFalse(t.make(b, (x => x.Secret == 4)));
    }
```